# How to proxy php-fpm program in Docker with Nginx installed outside of Docker

Tags: php, docker, nginx

Assume I have a php-fpm program inside a Docker container (for example [bitnami/bitnami-docker-php-fpm](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-php-fpm)), and I don't want to use a Nginx container, how can I proxy it with Nginx installed outside of Docker?

Comment: Don't you just have to give the address and port to Nginx as configuration? You can determine the address using `docker inspect`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, if you are running the **Nginx ingress** controller or one specific container of **Nginx**

**POD**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: example-app
labels:
  app: example-app
spec:
  containers:
  - name: example-app
    image: example-app:1.0
    ports:
    - containerPort: 9000
      name: fastcgi
```

Serivce

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: example-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: example-app
  ports:
  - port: 9000
    targetPort: 9000
    name: fastcgi
```

**ingress**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: example-cm
data:
  SCRIPT_FILENAME: "/example/index.php"

---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "FCGI"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/fastcgi-index: "index.php"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/fastcgi-params-configmap: "example-cm"
  name: example-app
spec:
  rules:
  - host: app.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: example-service
            port:
              name: fastcgi
```

Ref document : https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/fcgi-services/

If your Nginx running outside of docker you can use the host machine IP

```
server {
    listen  80;

    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/test;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/.+\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass 192.168.59.103:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }
}
```